# Globalmousekeyhook xmouse suppression

Tags: c#

I am using the globalmousekeyhook library ([here](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook)). Everything is fine but I want to suppress Xmouse1 and Xmouse2 (extra mouse buttons) clicks in other programs.

It is working with middle mouse button but does not work (my program and other programs too intercept clicks) with xmouse buttons.

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.XButton1) { e.Handled = true; }
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.XButton2) { e.Handled = true; }
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle) { e.Handled = true; } //working
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Does it actually *detect*, and fire your code for, `XButton1` and `XButton2` presses?

Comment: Yes. But I removed other codes in this sample. It is working good but other programs intercept the clicks also. Eg. browsers do a forward / back action with xmouse buttons. (If you want I can create a complete sample.)

Comment: It is possible that the mouse is sending some *other* value for the extended buttons.  This would depend on the mouse software.  For example, I have a Logitech mouse that is currently set to send the Media-Back as a key-press instead of sending the *real* mouse event.  You may need to hook the keyboard as well, and look for these special Media keys.

Comment: I wrote an autohotkey script which intercept the xmouse1 click. It is working good and suppress click in other programs. So I think the problem is with  globalmousekeyhook library.